# Android - How to add ListView in Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

I would add ListView in Fragment.

This is my activitymain.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tabAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="All"/>
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tabTravel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Travel"/>
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tabTech"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tech"/>

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

I have the list_item.xml where I have developed the custom layout.

My Fragment.java class:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){// Inflate the layout for this fragment
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);    }
```

When I try to add my adapter.java class I receive this error:
"cannot resolve method findviewbyid in fragment"

Comment: post your fragment class code, probably need to edit  to "view.findViewById"

Comment: Hi, I added fragment class code in the main post.

Comment: can you provide the link?

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){// Inflate the layout for this fragment
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);    }

Comment: complete class code and post the logcat complete error

Comment: I add you a screen about the error: https://ibb.co/FqYNfGL

Comment: You made several very basic mistakes, read the documentation, and always clear the basics first before copy-pasting.  Anyway, provided you a solution with your modified code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking your screen-shot, you made several mistakes
Correct them.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false); 

  // whatever you have written after this, move to the below method.
}

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


   // blah 
    ArrayList<CouponCategory> couponcategory = whatever you have written

   //
   ListView couponcategoryListView = view.findViewById(R.id.your_list_id);

   // whatever you have written....\
   // adapter initialization
   // settinh up blah...

    }
```

Comment: Thank you notTdar. Sure, before to post here, I read the documentation but don't find the solution. I followed your suggestion and I have the same error of before on this line:
CouponCategoryAdapter adapter = new CouponCategoryAdapter(this, couponcategory); Where, on "this, couponcategory);" Android Studio suggest me to change the 1st parameter on the adapter from Context to Allfragment..

Comment: believe me, you have not gone through very basics,   instead of this @parameter, pass --> view.getContext()

Comment: Thank you @notTdar. I solved my problem. I am newbie, please sorry if I ask something so simple

Comment: It is very important to go through multiple tutorials for very basics things in and out. Given that android documentation sometimes can be overwhelming, that is why you must check for other tutorials and get comfortable with it. I hope you can deduce the gist.